# Giving different score points for different questions

Tags: python

How do I make it give different score points for different questions? say 30 points for the first question, 35 for second and third (total 100)

Thanks

```
from Question import Question

question_prompts = ["What color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blue\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
                    "What color are bananas?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blue\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
                    "What color are strawberries?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blue\n(c) Yellow\n\n"]


questions = [Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
             Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
             Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
             ]


def sayhi(name):
    print("Hello " + name + "!\n")
sayhi("Alice")


def run(question):
    score = 0
    for getInput in question:  
        answer = input(getInput.prompt)  
        if answer == getInput.answer:
            score += 2
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(question *2)) + " correct!")


run(questions)
```

Question.py

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):

        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

Comment: add a `score` attribute ?

Comment: `question_prompt = [ ("question", value) ]` may be all that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add the attribute 'score' to the question class.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer, score):

        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
        self.score = score
```

Then, pass the scores for each question as the third parameter as you wish.

```
questions = [Question(question_prompts[0], "a", 30),
             Question(question_prompts[1], "c", 30),
             Question(question_prompts[2], "b", 35),
             ]
```

So your logic to compute the final score changes to below:

```
def run(question):
    score = 0
    for getInput in question:  
        answer = input(getInput.prompt)  
        if answer == getInput.answer:
            score += getInput.score
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(question * 2)) + " correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want another attribute:

```
def run(question):
    score = 0
    for index, getInput in enumerate(question):
        answer = input(getInput.prompt)
        if (index == 0) and (answer == getInput.answer):
            score += 30
        elif answer == getInput.answer:
            score += 35
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + '100' + " correct!")
```

But in general Chandra's approach is better

Answer (score 0):

One options if there are no other restrictions could be - Add an attribute `score` to your Question class and use it while calculating the score. Also, you need to calculate/track total possible score separately.

Something like below would work:

```
Question.py
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer, score):

        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
        self.score = score

def run(question):
    score = 0
    total_possible_score = 0
    for getInput in question:
        total_possible_score += getInput.score  
        answer = input(getInput.prompt)  
        if answer == getInput.answer:
            score += getInput.score
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(total_possible_score) + " correct!")
```